# IIS combined with WatiN system.nullreferenceexception

Tags: c#, iis, watin

So im having a bit off a problem, when creating a new instance off FireFox with WatiN.

Some Info you might find important!

1. I am able to run this code on IIS Exspress, and in winform.
2. .Net Trust level is on Full(internal) with admin credentials.
3. I also set all References to Copy Local = true (i did this after the exeption started taking place)

the error happens here:

```
  public string msg(string username, string password, string msg, string group, List<string> id, bool test)
    {
        using (FireFox _FF = new FireFox())//nullreferenceexception
        {
           a lot of code
        }
    }
```

This is what calls the msg:

```
  else if (RadioButton1.Checked)
           {
               msgbot.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
               msgbot.Start();
               msgbot.Join();
           }
           blocker = true;
           }
           Server.Transfer("Done.aspx", true);
       }
       protected void sendmsgtobot()
       { 
       msger.msg("username", "password", TextBox1.Text , "159347", ids , false);
    }
```

Comment: I am stuck with the same error. If you send any URL to the FireFox constructor, you get a different stack trace, but it's still a very meaningless exception message with no inner exceptions...